# Forcing a Classified Document to Another Layout within Hyperscience

Tags: json, python-3.x, classification

I want to force a document to classify against a particular layout on Hyperscience - is this possible? I can use the `uuid`, `layout_uuid`, `layout_version_uuid`, along with other metadata. I also want to include the pages belonging to the document if it has been classified already.

I’ve already set up the custom code block to perform this function as below:

```
def force_classification(submission: Any) -> Any:
    ***insert code here***
    return submission

cct_force_classification = CodeBlock(
    reference_name='force_classification',
    code=force_classification,
    code_input={'submission': previous_block.output('submission')},
    title='Force Classification',
    description='Force Classification',
)
```

Reading the SDK docs, I didn't see a clear way to do this. I'm wondering if this is just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible! However, there are some limitations. You are able to use a custom code block to specify the layout that a document must be classified against if it has already been classified, as long as the layout that you’re forcing classification against is a semi-structured layout.

```
new_documents = []
for document in submission.get('documents', []):
    if document['layout_uuid'] == 'layout_uuid[1]':
        new_document = {
            'uuid': document['id'],
            'layout_version_uuid': 'layout_version_uuid[2]',
            'layout_uuid': 'layout_uuid[1]',
            'pages': [{
                'submission_page_id': page['id'],
                'page_number': page['submission_page_number'],
                'classification_type': page['classification_type'],
            } for page in document.get('pages', [])],
            'metadata': {},
        }
        new_documents.append(new_document)

return {'submission': submission, 'new_documents': new_documents}
```

Note that, here, layout_uuid[1] refers to an existing document, and 2 corresponds to the metadata of the other layout you want to force classification against.

Keep in mind that this is still superficial (client side) and will not reflect in the Hyperscience db until you sync this new document back.